# fast report class missing after update RAD XE2

Tags: delphi

I just did the update of RAD XE2 to the latest service pack.  I can not compile my application using Fast reports stuff inside. The error at compile says "frxclass.dcu not found".
This seems to be a problem like 
[FAST REPORT ISSUE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158064/fastreport-4-0-claas-tfrxreport-not-found-exception-rad-studio-xe2)

Is this a bug of updateing XE2 or did I do something wrong while executing the update process ?

Comment: I saw something similiar when I've updated XE2: it seemed to me that bobtailed FR which is part of XE2 installation overwrote my FR professional installation and I had to uninstall FR and install professional version manually again. But I don't remember details.

Comment: Do you own your own separate copy of FastReports?

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens with XE2 and XE3. I have FR professional with source and have done several installations each of which have suffered problems. I believe that it is an incompatibility between the included version of FR and the licenced version. My solution was thorough:
1. Go into control panel and delete any and all installations of FR.
2. Go to the program files folder and manually delete any FR folders.
3. Inside the Delphi IDE go into options, library and locate and delete any reference to fast report paths.
4. Go into the IDE Install Packages option and make sure that there are no references to FR packages.
5. Quit the IDE and now install FR using the supplied installer. When this completes you should be able to fire up the IDE fine without frClass errors.