# Creating custom controls. Do I have to give them a name?

Tags: delphi

Let's say I create (from TPanel) and install my own control. It contains only one button:

```
constructor TMyPanel.Create(aOwner: TComponent);
begin
 inherited Create(aOwner);

 btn:= TButton.Create(Self);
 btn.Parent:= Self;   
 btn.Name:= 'xxx';      <-------- mandatory?
end;
```

Is it mandatory to give a name to that panel?

---

This question started from a comment posted by dummzeuch here:

> This happens when your label doesn't have a name. The IDE adds
>   declarations to the class only if the control has got a name (how else
>   should it declare it?).

[What does a EClassNotFound raised at runtime really mean when the class in question is there at compile and link time, and there explicitly in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287204/what-does-a-eclassnotfound-raised-at-runtime-really-mean-when-the-class-in-quest/53253048?noredirect=1#comment93437484_53253048)

(I am specifically refer to that comment only)

Comment: You are mixing apples and oranges. Linked question was about streaming from dfm, and here you are creating control in code. No, you don't need a name, but you might want to set it as sub component.

Comment: The IDE needs components to have a name, but otherwise no. So if the IDE does not *directly* access any of the properties of the subcomponent then it does not need a name. This does not stop the properties of the component being set by the parent, for example via a property of the parent that is visible to the IDE.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar - Nope. I was not speaking about that question. I was speaking about one VERY specific comment (that was also not answering that question).

Comment: @Dsm - thanks. I was not naming my sub-controls. And as you said, it was working ok. But that comment got me worrying: "what if I was doing it wrong all the time" ? If you post this as answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar - the control i show here will be IN THE END also streamed when I drop it on my form and save the project/the form. anyway my question is is about assigning a name to a sub-control.

Comment: Comment posted as answer, as requested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you do not need to name sub components.

However, if you intent on exposing access to a sub componenet as a property that gets streamed in a DFM, you do need to mark the sub component, at least:

```
constructor TMyPanel.Create(aOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(aOwner);
  btn := TButton.Create(Self);
  btn.Parent := Self;
  btn.SetSubComponent(True); // <-- ADD THIS
end;
```

Comment: "SetSubComponent" - oh... yeah!

Answer (score 2):

The IDE needs components to have a name, but otherwise no. So if the IDE does not directly access any of the properties of the subcomponent then it does not need a name. This does not stop the properties of the component being set by the parent, for example via a property of the parent that is visible to the IDE.